# NullReferenceException when setting a out parameter in c#

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, unsafe, easyhook

I got a unsafe assembly using easyhook in c#.. this code bellows works well
but sum time, I got a NullReferenceException when this method is called..

The instance of this class is a Singleton pattern
It passe several time and one point it got a null reference

This class if for intercept all writing in some I/O file to proceed some operation

Any ideas
See code..

OCCURS ONLY WHEN SQLCOMMAND executed

> at ....SystemHook.WriteFileHook(IntPtr hFile, Void* lpBuffer, UInt32
>   nNumberOfBytesToWrite, UInt32& lpNumberOfBytesWritten,
>   NativeOverlapped& lpOverlapped) 
>  at
>   SNIWriteSyncOverAsync(SNI_ConnWrapper* , SNI_Packet* )
>  at
>   SNINativeMethodWrapper.SNIWritePacket(SafeHandle pConn, SafeHandle
>   packet, Boolean sync)
>  at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.SNIWritePacket(SNIHandle
>   handle, SNIPacket packet, UInt32& sniError, Boolean canAccumulate,
>   Boolean callerHasConnectionLock)
>  at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.WriteSni(Boolean
>   canAccumulate)
>  at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.WritePacket(Byte flushMode,
>   Boolean canAccumulate)
>  at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ExecuteFlush()
>  at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteSQLBatch(String text, Int32
>   timeout, SqlNotificationRequest notificationRequest,
>   TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean sync, Boolean
>   callerHasConnectionLock, Byte[] enclavePackage)
>  at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry,
>   SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
>  at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
>  at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method)
>  at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)
>  at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)
>  at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()

```
bool WriteFileHook(IntPtr hFile, void* lpBuffer, uint nNumberOfBytesToWrite, out uint lpNumberOfBytesWritten, [In] ref System.Threading.NativeOverlapped lpOverlapped)
{

    bool results = false;
    bool write = true;

    lpNumberOfBytesWritten = 0; // CRASH!!!

    ... 
}
```

Comment: Change to uint?  The question mark will allow nulls.  Then lpNumberOfBytesWritten = lpNumberOfBytesWritten == null ? null : 0;

Comment: this scalar assignment cannot cause a (managed) NullReferenceException. post full exception details including call stack.

Comment: You've got unsafe code here which means **all the usual safety systems are turned off**. You should be very happy that this is crashing when it is called incorrectly, rather than corrupting user data or CLR data structures; that means you can at least track down the problem. Start by looking at the call stack carefully.

Comment: Additionnal information, look like it occurs only when a sql command executed

Comment: now this could become interesting. I guess the sql command execution triggers the hook because you are connected to SQL Server via a named pipe? now you posted the call stack but still exception details are missing. full code of hook handler? which line in there?

Comment: I'm connecting to local SQL serveur

Comment: Try uint* or ref uint instead to correctly match the native signature LPDWORD.

Comment: **thanks Justin!!! it works**

Answer (score 0):

[Justin Stenning](https://stackoverflow.com/users/323899/justin-stenning) was right in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54160596/nullreferenceexception-when-setting-a-out-parameter-in-c-sharp/54165074#comment95158087_54160596):

> Try uint* or ref uint instead to correctly match the native signature LPDWORD.

I had the wrong signature.